# D3. zoom() position jumps when zoom() is initialized

Tags: d3.js

When I draw the force-oriented diagram, the nodes are shifted when I shrink them，
and in the other hand,Coordinate offset problem after zooming in and out of the picture during svg intertext drawing.How can I fix it
The javascript file:

```
      .attr("x", function (d) {
          return (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2;
        });*/

      gs
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>建筑力导向图</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="960" height="800"></svg>
  <script src = "./data.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
  <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>


   /**********************************初始化svg******************************/
  var margin = {
    top:60,
    bottom:60,
    left:60,
    right:60
  }
  var svg = d3.select("svg")
    svg.call(d3.zoom()
       .scaleExtent([0.5,10])
       .on("zoom",zoomed))
       .on("dblclick.zoom",null)
       .append("g");
  var width = svg.attr("width")
  var height = svg.attr("height")
  var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+margin.top+","+margin.left+")");
  function zoomed(){
    let d = d3.selectAll("g")
    d.attr("transform",d3.event.transform).append("g");
    console.log("重新构建力导向");
    }
    .....................
     var gs = g.selectAll(".circleText")
      .data(nodesArray)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        var cirX = d.x;
        var cirY = d.y;
        return "translate(" + cirX + "," + cirY + ")";
      })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", started)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", ended)
      );



    //绘制节点
    gs.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return colorScale(i);
      })
   

    function started(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) {
        forceSimulation.alphaTarget(0.8).restart();
      }
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }
    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }
    function ended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) {
        forceSimulation.alphaTarget(0);
      }
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
type here
```

After the automatic transition, when the user tries to pan or zoom - the rectangles jump back to their intitial position.
I tried a few things but still couldn't solve the problem